# Is there anyway to execute system commands via LDAP command line?

Tags: linux, bash, ldap

In linux system,I know that we can execute system commands via Mysql command like by using !  . I would like to know if we can do something like that via LDAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the question is not fully correct. When you run shell commands from mysql client, you just run shell commands. These commands are not related to mysql. That is just a convinient way to run something from the mysql client without leaving it.

There are nos such clients for LDAP. All commands that you can use to access a LDAP-server are non-interactive: `ldapsearch`, `ldapadd`, `ldapmodify` and so on. So you are not able "escape" them.

Answer (score 1):

Most LDAP server implementations provide command line utilities.

Some common command-line utilities are:

ldapcompare — perform LDAP compare operations 
ldapdelete perform LDAP delete operations 
ldapmodify — perform LDAP modify, add, delete, mod DN operations 
ldappasswordmodify — perform LDAP password modifications 
ldapsearch — perform LDAP search operations

Thought they could vary by LDAP server implementation.

A reference to a specific LDAP server implementation is found at: 
http://opendj.forgerock.org/doc/admin-guide/index/admin-tools-ref.html

-jim